# Android Studio Layout preview not showing design

Tags: android, android-studio

I am currently working on a project and everything was fine. Today, while I opened android studio, the design/layout preview showing white screen only. (Like the picture)

I did try:

1. Invalidate Cache and Restart
2. Force Layout Refresh
3. Downgrading appcombat to 27.1.1
4. Adding Base.Theme in style.xml

But, nothing worked. **No Build errors, runs fine in emulator and design shows in emulator, but not in android studio.**

Any solution would be a great help, also let me know if you need more details.

[image]

Even a new project with Hello World layout appears same. Tried, uninstalling and installing Android Studio.
[image]

Comment: please provide the xml of your layout

Comment: Do you have any error in the build tab?

Comment: @TouhidulIslam, even fresh layout shows like this, adding content doesn't show anything.

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi, No build errors, even app runs fine and design shows in emulator.

Comment: The component tree on the left side shows some red marks. What do they say?

Comment: @Christopher, even a fresh layout doesn't show up. You can see the attributes pane, it's missing common things like id, width, height attributes.

Comment: Invalidate Caches & restart Android Studio worked for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know what was wrong, but below steps solved my problem:

1. Clear caches folder from C:/Users//.grade/caches
2. Clear caches folder from C:/Users//.AndroidStuido3.x/system/caches
3. Restart Android Studio
4. Clean build project

After hours of experimenting and going through lots of solutions, this was the one that actually worked.

Hope anyone in the future faces this problem will find this helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Chenge the theme in the design screen,and you can see your perview.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue resolved following this steps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMbIUVogWTo

In short answer is change appcompact-v7 "beta01" to "alpha1"

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21354921)

Comment: I have edited answer... hope this will help... and thank you so much for highlight and down vote...

Answer (score 0):

Try these, they are worked for me :

1.Rebuild project Buil > Rebuild project

2. Invalidate and caches
3. Gradale synch Setting>Synch project with gradle files

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried all the solution and still problem is not solved the try doing this- just disable the toggle icon (top right icon) in xml as your layout would be visible in only night mode. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9FfC.png)

Answer (score -1):

I just created a new Project and copied all the code based into the new project and then it was working fine.